# Linear Algebra, Frobenius Norm

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A\in M_n(R)$ a square matrix of order n.
I know by definition of Frobenius Norm that $|||A|||_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2}$ and I need to show that $|||A|||_F=\sqrt{tr{(A^tA)}}$ where $A^t$ is a transposed matrix and tr is a trace of matrix.

Comment: What is the standard definition of that norm? What do we have to work with, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply the definition of matrix-matrix multiplication.
\begin{align}
A &= [a_{ij}]_{ij}\\
C &= A^{T}A\\
C_{ii} &= \sum_{j}a_{ji}^{2}\\
tr(C) &= \sum_{i}C_{ii}\\
 &= \sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_{ji}^{2}\\
 &= ||A||_{F}^{2}
\end{align}

Comment: What the first line means? [aij]ij?

Comment: @askazy It just means I represent the individual elements of $A$ by $a_{ij}$.